# Multiple queries on one prepared statement object

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I am trying to do 2 completely unrelated queries on a mysql database with prepared statements in php. Is it possible to do this with one prepared statement object, or do I need more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are they the same statement but with different conditions? ie:

```
UPDATE users SET email=? WHERE user_id=?
```

Which you would then call multiple times with your various emails and user_ids.

That's basically what prepared statements are for. The query planner can then plan once and execute many times.

If you have two different queries thought then you could overwrite the statement of your prepared statement object, and you may save an insignificant amount of time by not insubstantiating a new object, but you're not actually getting added efficiency of prepared statements.

Comment: No. As I said, the queries are unrelated but both require prepared statements.

Comment: Then yes you should be able to redefine the object with `$stmt->prepare();` You'll manage to avoid `$stmt->init()` but that's about it. It's unlikely to have any noticeable effect on the running time.